# The specified type was not recognized error deserializing STIX XML

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I have an STIX XML as below when i created model class in .net using this xml and tried to deserialize I am getting the below error -

```
{"The specified type was not recognized: name='PackageIntentVocab-1.0', 
namespace='http://stix.mitre.org/default_vocabularies-1', at <Package_Intent xmlns='http://stix.mitre.org/stix-1'>."}
```

Can anyone help me in get rid of this error?

Thanks

Comment: show us an example of the xml and the c# model

Comment: Model XML is in the link - https://www.us-cert.gov/sites/default/files/publications/JAR-16-20296A.xml

Comment: C# Model class - Too big to share here so adding one property alone                     [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Package_Intent", Namespace = "http://stix.mitre.org/stix-1")]
    public class Package_Intent
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Model XML is in the link - https://www.us-cert.gov/sites/default/files/publications/JAR-16-20296A.xml

Comment: Can i get any help on this?